# planetaryjs globe not working - javascript

Tags: javascript, planetary.js

I want this type of globe and I am using [planetaryjs](http://planetaryjs.com/) for this.

I have added the necessary resources for that in external resources link
including all js files and data file.
why the globe is not loading?

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/4dmq49zm/6/)

```
(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('quakeCanvas');

  // Create our Planetary.js planet and set some initial values;
  // we use several custom plugins, defined at the bottom of the file
  var planet = planetaryjs.planet();
  planet.loadPlugin(autocenter({extraHeight: -120}));
  planet.loadPlugin(autoscale({extraHeight: -120}));
  planet.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.earth({
    topojson: { file:   '/world-110m.json' },
    oceans:   { fill:   '#001320' },
    land:     { fill:   '#06304e' },
    borders:  { stroke: '#001320' }
  }));
  planet.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.pings());
  planet.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.zoom({
    scaleExtent: [50, 5000]
  }));
  planet.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.drag({
    onDragStart: function() {
      this.plugins.autorotate.pause();
    },
    onDragEnd: function() {
      this.plugins.autorotate.resume();
    }
  }));
  planet.loadPlugin(autorotate(5));
  planet.projection.rotate([100, -10, 0]);
  planet.draw(canvas);


  // Create a color scale for the various earthquake magnitudes; the
  // minimum magnitude in our data set is 2.5.
  var colors = d3.scale.pow()
    .exponent(3)
    .domain([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
      .range(['white', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'purple']);
  // Also create a scale for mapping magnitudes to ping angle sizes
  var angles = d3.scale.pow()
    .exponent(3)
    .domain([2.5, 10])
    .range([0.5, 15]);
  // And finally, a scale for mapping magnitudes to ping TTLs
  var ttls = d3.scale.pow()
    .exponent(3)
    .domain([2.5, 10])
    .range([2000, 5000]);

  // Create a key to show the magnitudes and their colors
  d3.select('#magnitudes').selectAll('li')
    .data(colors.ticks(9))
  .enter()
    .append('li')
    .style('color', colors)
    .text(function(d) {
      return "Magnitude " + d;
    });


  // Load our earthquake data and set up the controls.
  // The data consists of an array of objects in the following format:
  // {
  //   mag:  magnitude_of_quake
  //   lng:  longitude_coordinates
  //   lat:  latitude_coordinates
  //   time: timestamp_of_quake
  // }
  // The data is ordered, with the earliest data being the first in the file.
  d3.json('/examples/quake/year_quakes_small.json', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      alert("Problem loading the quake data.");
      return;
    }

    var start = parseInt(data[0].time, 10);
    var end = parseInt(data[data.length - 1].time, 10);
    var currentTime = start;
    var lastTick = new Date().getTime();

    var updateDate = function() {
      d3.select('#date').text(moment(currentTime).utc().format("MMM DD YYYY HH:mm UTC"));
    };

    // A scale that maps a percentage of playback to a time
    // from the data; for example, `50` would map to the halfway
    // mark between the first and last items in our data array.
    var percentToDate = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([start, end]);

    // A scale that maps real time passage to data playback time.
    // 12 minutes of real time maps to the entirety of the
    // timespan covered by the data.
    var realToData = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 1000 * 60 * 12])
      .range([0, end - start]);

    var paused = false;

    // Pause playback and update the time display
    // while scrubbing using the range input.
    d3.select('#slider')
      .on('change', function(d) {
        currentTime = percentToDate(d3.event.target.value);
        updateDate();
      })
      .call(d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('dragstart', function() {
          paused = true;
        })
        .on('dragend', function() {
          paused = false;
        })
      );


    // The main playback loop; for each tick, we'll see how much
    // time passed in our accelerated playback reel and find all
    // the earthquakes that happened in that timespan, adding
    // them to the globe with a color and angle relative to their magnitudes.
    d3.timer(function() {
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      if (paused) {
        lastTick = now;
        return;
      }

      var realDelta = now - lastTick;
      // Avoid switching back to the window only to see thousands of pings;
      // if it's been more than 500 milliseconds since we've updated playback,
      // we'll just set the value to 500 milliseconds.
      if (realDelta > 500) realDelta = 500;
      var dataDelta = realToData(realDelta);

      var toPing = data.filter(function(d) {
        return d.time > currentTime && d.time <= currentTime + dataDelta;
      });

      for (var i = 0; i < toPing.length; i++) {
        var ping = toPing[i];
        planet.plugins.pings.add(ping.lng, ping.lat, {
          // Here we use the `angles` and `colors` scales we built earlier
          // to convert magnitudes to appropriate angles and colors.
          angle: angles(ping.mag),
          color: colors(ping.mag),
          ttl:   ttls(ping.mag)
        });
      }

      currentTime += dataDelta;
      if (currentTime > end) currentTime = start;
      updateDate();
      d3.select('#slider').property('value', percentToDate.invert(currentTime));
      lastTick = now;
    });
  });



  // Plugin to resize the canvas to fill the window and to
  // automatically center the planet when the window size changes
  function autocenter(options) {
    options = options || {};
    var needsCentering = false;
    var globe = null;

    var resize = function() {
      var width  = window.innerWidth + (options.extraWidth || 0);
      var height = window.innerHeight + (options.extraHeight || 0);
      globe.canvas.width = width;
      globe.canvas.height = height;
      globe.projection.translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
    };

    return function(planet) {
      globe = planet;
      planet.onInit(function() {
        needsCentering = true;
        d3.select(window).on('resize', function() {
          needsCentering = true;
        });
      });

      planet.onDraw(function() {
        if (needsCentering) { resize(); needsCentering = false; }
      });
    };
  };

  // Plugin to automatically scale the planet's projection based
  // on the window size when the planet is initialized
  function autoscale(options) {
    options = options || {};
    return function(planet) {
      planet.onInit(function() {
        var width  = window.innerWidth + (options.extraWidth || 0);
        var height = window.innerHeight + (options.extraHeight || 0);
        planet.projection.scale(Math.min(width, height) / 2);
      });
    };
  };

  // Plugin to automatically rotate the globe around its vertical
  // axis a configured number of degrees every second.
  function autorotate(degPerSec) {
    return function(planet) {
      var lastTick = null;
      var paused = false;
      planet.plugins.autorotate = {
        pause:  function() { paused = true;  },
        resume: function() { paused = false; }
      };
      planet.onDraw(function() {
        if (paused || !lastTick) {
          lastTick = new Date();
        } else {
          var now = new Date();
          var delta = now - lastTick;
          var rotation = planet.projection.rotate();
          rotation[0] += degPerSec * delta / 1000;
          if (rotation[0] >= 180) rotation[0] -= 360;
          planet.projection.rotate(rotation);
          lastTick = now;
        }
      });
    };
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your globe is not loading for multiple reasons. First, if you open up your console you would see that the external resources were not loaded properly. As the error notes, your external resources failed to load because:

```
 MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

You could overcome this issue in a twofold manner. You could either refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049842/6655569) answer--which will help you sort the MIME type issue--or you may just use other links for you external resources. If you rather take the second route, you should add the links below to your external resources section, in the following order:

1. [moment.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js)
2. [d3.js](https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js)
3. [planetary.js](https://labs.rivendellweb.net/data-vis/planetary/planetaryjs.js)

After you solved the first issue, you will see that you would not be able to link your JSON file by simply adding it to your external resources. [These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484924/how-can-i-link-external-json-file-in-jsfiddle) will offer you multiple approaches that will help you solve the JSON issue as well.

After you have successfully linked all of your external files, you will face a third problem. If you look at your code you will see that you are trying to get the ***time*** property for your *data* (JSON) object in line 75--`var start = parseInt(data[0].time, 10);`. However, as far as I could tell, your data object does not hold a ***time*** property--go ahead, and `console.log()` your data object to see its structure and properties. In other words, you might want to double check if the `world-110m.json` is the file that you want to work with.

Hope this helps.